# How to release memory allocated for a variable using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Is there a method to release memory allocated to a variable in vbscript?

For ex: x=10
When this statement is executed memory is allocated and the value is stored in that memory.

Is there a method to release that memory.

I know once the execution is over or the variable is out of scope from a function the memory is automatically released, but is there a method to release it?

Comment: I know how to relelase memory for arrays and objects, but i am looking for variables.Will variable=empty releases the memory allocated to a variable?

Comment: Your question has already been answered with "no" by at least 2 people.

Answer (score 2):

The [Erase statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8yk5k45%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

> Reinitializes the elements of fixed-size arrays and deallocates
>   dynamic-array storage space.

For long strings assignment with "" **may** prod the garbage collector to deallocate the now orphaned long text.

Trying to reclaim the memory for numbers or dates would be a waste of effort.

Answer (score 2):

Each variable used some memory until exist, even `Nothing Is Object`!

```
Set myObj = Nothing
WScript.Echo "IsObject = " & IsObject(myObj)
WScript.Echo "IsNothing = " & (myObj Is Nothing)
'>> IsObject = True
'>> IsNothing = True
```

(Note: `Is` operator compares two object reference variables.)

Answer (score 1):

If it is an object the just set it to Nothing

Answer (score 0):

The memory allocated for object variables can freed by setting the variable to `Nothing` as [@StephenConnolly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15859658/1630171) mentioned:

```
Set var = Nothing
```

There is no explicit way to free the memory allocated for scalar variables.

Comment: please remove "array" from your answer.

Comment: I am asking about releasing memory for variables. I knew about arrays and objects.